# I used ionicons in my project , but it can not be showed

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionicons

As the title says,I used the follow element in my project but it can not be showed.

```
<i class="ion-android-checkbox"></i>
```

I do not know how to solve this problem.If someone can tell me how to solve this problem, thank you very much.

Comment: too less info to work on this. please provide codes / fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. I hope this can helps someone.

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionicons-breaking-on-ionic-beta-13-fixed/13640